# invoke grpc method on server without client request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

I have grpc connection between client and server.

At the beginning client send message to server and connection is created.

Server has a background process that after checking something and conditions are true it should send message to client.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything without the client making a request. I assume what's *actually* important is that the client doesn't need to know *when* to make a request, because the server is effectively event-based.

Create a server-streaming method, and call it from the client. The server can provide responses whenever it wants, and the client will then need to read those responses and handle them.